# How can I calcuate wrapping text height in a famo.us surface?

Tags: famo.us

Within famo.us, I want to place a variable-length wrapping title near the top then have images etc follow. All items must be their own surface as some have click events and animations but all the positioning must be super fast to calculate and place based on the text height and of course must avoid DOM access for the 60fps. This must happen for a series of mini-posts, streaming real time and for infinite scroll.

So far, I came up with an approach that works using an ascii character map to pixel width load off screen on init if isn't already in localStorage. It uses jquery to do the sizing for each character, then determine line height by checking a breaking word and the height of that box. After that I use this map for calculations on the fly so I don't touch DOM again. It seems to work fine but is completely dependent on knowing the style of font going to be used in a very specific way. For each new style, I would have to have a different mapping which sucks.

Is there another approach that is more built in to famo.us?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question because its frankly been awhile, the new framework is going to come out June 22nd of this month (at the time of the this writing). Just going to put how I'm doing this currently which is the way I described above.

Here's the 0.3.5 way of Famou.us to do this.

This is in a file "utils/lines.js" I whipped up. Hack, yes. Works, yes.

```
    define(function(require) {
      'use strict';

      var $ = require('jquery');
      var cache = require('utils/cache');

      function getLineInfo(id) {
        var cacheKey = 'lineInfo_' + id;
        var savedLineInfo = cache.get(cacheKey);
        if (savedLineInfo)
          return savedLineInfo;

        var charStart = 32; // space
        var charEnd = 126; // ~
        var $charDump = $('<div>', { id: id });
        $('body').append($charDump);

        for (var i = charStart; i <= charEnd; i++)
          $charDump.append($('<div>', { class: 'char', css: { top: (i-32) * 20 } }).html('&#' + i));

        var charMap = {};
        $charDump.find('.char').each(function() {
          var $this = $(this);
          var char = $this.text().charCodeAt(0);
          var w = $this.width();
          charMap[char] = w;
        });
        $charDump.html('<div class="line">abc<br>123<br>456</div>');
        var lineHeight = $charDump.height() / 3;
        $charDump.remove();
        savedLineInfo = {
          lineHeight: lineHeight,
          charMap: charMap
        };
        cache.set(cacheKey, savedLineInfo);
        return savedLineInfo;
      }

      function getLines(text, width, id, maxLines) {
        var lineInfo = getLineInfo(id);
        var cleaned = $.trim(text.replace(/\s+/gm, ' '));
        var words = cleaned.split(' ');
        var lines = 1;
        var lineWidth = 0;
        var spaceLength = lineInfo.charMap[32];
        var allLines = '';
        words.forEach(function(word) {
          var wordLength = 0;
          word.split('').forEach(function(char) {
            var charLength = lineInfo.charMap[char.charCodeAt(0)];
            if (!charLength)
              charLength = spaceLength;
            wordLength += charLength;
          });
          if (lineWidth + wordLength + spaceLength <= width) {
            lineWidth += wordLength + spaceLength;
            if (maxLines)
              allLines += word + ' ';
          }
          else {
            lineWidth = wordLength;
            if (maxLines && lines <= maxLines)
              allLines += word + ' ';
            else if (maxLines)
              return {text: allLines.substr(0, allLines.length - 3) + '...', lines: lines};
            lines++;
          }
        });
        if (maxLines)
          return {text: allLines, lines: lines};
        return lines;
      }

      function getTextHeight(text, width, id, maxLines) {
        var lineInfo = getLineInfo(id);
        var info;
        if (maxLines) {
          info = getLines(text, width, id, maxLines);
          info.height = lineInfo.lineHeight * info.lines;
          return info;
        }
        return lineInfo.lineHeight * getLines(text, width, id);
      }

      return {
        getLines: getLines,
        getLineInfo: getLineInfo,
        getTextHeight: getTextHeight
      };
});
```